# Scrapy Selenium to crawl JS loaded web page

Tags: javascript, selenium, dynamic, scrapy, web-crawler

now I am going to practice crawling a website, which is javascript loaded.
I use chrome to inspect element and I can find the corresponding code, but when I view page source, I can find nothing.

Specifically, I am crawling https://ifttt.com/augusthome, and I hope to get applet-URLs in this web page.

What I am doing now is using scrapy and selenium like below.

```
def parse(self, response):
    print("procesing:"+response.url)
    # print(response.body)
    # blog_urls=response.xpath("//li[@class='my-web-applet-card web-applet-card'][4]").extract()
    # print(blog_urls)
    self.browser.get(response.url)
    tt=self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='my-web-applet-card web-applet-card'][4]")
    print(tt)


def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    # Called with the response returned from the downloader.

    # Must either;
    # - return a Response object
    # - return a Request object
    # - or raise IgnoreRequest
    spider.browser.get(url=request.url)
    time.sleep(10)
    # row_response = spider.browser.page_source
    row_response = spider.browser.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')")
    print(row_response)
    return HtmlResponse(url=spider.browser.current_url, body=row_response, encoding="utf8", request=request)
```

Comment: The data for this page is from "https://ifttt.com/augusthome.json" so it might be better to directly access that

Comment: So cool! Thank you for your hint.